# Login Failure Messages are not being shown

Tags: 8, status-messages

I am using Drupal 8 with the Bootstrap 3 theme.

When a user on our site tries to log in unsuccessfully, no failure message are displayed. Is there something I can change anywhere in settings to show a message when the user fails to log in?

I know that eventually, the `UserAuthenticationController::login` method processes the user/login POST request and will return a `BadRequestHttpException` if the username and password are not correct with the text `'Sorry, unrecognized username or password.'`.

However, I don't see this or any other error message anywhere on the site when testing the login control with invalid usernames and passwords. I'm just returned to the login page with no error. Having spent days googling this and even digging into Drupal 8 core, I am sure I am missing something.

Does anyone have any ideas to try for this?

Comment: I guess you disabled the 'Status messages' block. Please check under `/admin/structure/block` and confirm.

Comment: "Status Messages" appears to be in our footer already.

Comment: Set the default theme to Bartik and try again. This will help eliminate a theme layer issue.

Comment: @FrustratedWithDrupal8 - That's where you want your failure messages etc. to appear? In the footer?